# eigenvalues ordering in numpy linalg

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a little confused about the output of the function np.linalg.eig().

As far as I understand, the eigenvalues should be ordered in the same way as the eigenvectors, so that the first eigenvalue corresponds to the first eigenvector.

"The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]."
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

However in this case here, it seems to be not the case:

```
In [109]: np.linalg.eig(np.array( ((0,1),(1,0))))
Out[109]: 
(array([ 1., -1.]), array([[ 0.70710678, -0.70710678],
    [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]]))
```

Am I misinterpreting this function or am I missing something else? It would be great if someone could help to clarify this for me :-)

Comment: Try printing `v[:,0]` and `v[:,1]`: perhaps you're confusing the rows and columns in NumPy notation.

Comment: ok, I call the output of this function v. I still see that v[0][0] = 1 and v[1][0] = array([0.70710678, -0.70710678]).  This combination of eigenvector and eigenvalue simply doesn't belong together.

Comment: ok, wait. i think I understand you now. these two vectors in the second array are just the rows. I was confusing this with a list of eigenvectors...  
Great, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes, it is returned as a 2D array, not as a list of vectors. Presumably so that the result can easily be used in further calculations.